# How to disable any data source resource during startup in tomcat or tcServer

Tags: tomcat7, datasource, connection-pooling, tcserver

In TcServer or Tomcate, Data source resource's which we create are getting loaded during startup. is there any way to stop any resource during startup.

Actually i have two data source resources with two different connection pooling.
want to enable one at a time. please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why don't you enable both datasource, and choose from your application

Comment: Yes that we can do . However in this case two different connection pool will be created with some minimum number of database connection in each pool. And we will loose memory for the connection which we will not use.